# Shortcode: Images not being returned after explode()

Tags: php, html, wordpress, explode, wpbakery

I've created a custom element which extends the `WPBakery` plugin. This custom element will be an image slider. Users choose how many images they want from the single backend option, and the images will then be exploded (`explode()`), returning and showing the images - That's the idea anyway.

However, I cannot figure out why my images are not being returned? The surrounding content is being rendered in the front end, but the `li`, in which the `src` of these images sit, they're empty. Also, I have three images in chosen in the backend, but on one `li` is being rendered.

**Here is the complete markup:**

```
<?php 
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    die( '-1' );
}

class vcImageCarousel extends WPBakeryShortCode {

    function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'vc_imageCarousel_mapping' ) );
        add_shortcode( 'vc_imageCarousel', array( $this, 'vc_imageCarousel_html' ) );
    }

    vc_map( 
        array(
            'name' => __('Image Carousel', 'text-domain'),
            'base' => 'vc_imageCarousel',
            'description' => __('Image Carousel', 'text-domain'), 
            'params' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'attach_images',
                    'heading' => esc_html__("Images"),
                    'param_name' => 'image',
                    'value' => esc_html__(''),
                    'admin_label' => false,
                    'weight' => 0,
                    'group' => __( 'Content', 'my-text-domain' ),
                )  
            )
        )
    );

    public function vc_imageCarousel_html( $atts ) {

        extract(
            shortcode_atts(
                array(
                    'id'                    => '',
                    'class'                 => '',
                ), 
                $atts
            )
        );

        // map background image attributes
        $image = shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'image' => 'image',
            ), 
            $atts 
        );

        $image_ids=explode(',',$image['image']);


        $result = "<div class='imageCarousel'>";
        $result .= "<div class='imageCarousel__container justify-content-center'>";
        $result .= "<ul>";

        foreach( $image_ids as $image_id ){
            $result .='<li>';
            $result .= var_dump($image_id);
            $result .= wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'full' );
            $result .='</li>';
        }

        $result .= "</ul>";
        $result .= "</div>";
        $result .= "</div>";

        return $result;


    }

}

new vcImageCarousel(); ?>
```

A `var_dump($image_id)` returns `string(5) "image"`.

Comment: `$result .= var_dump($image_id);` The `var_dump` function does not return anything, but rather writes its output directly to the screen.

Comment: I would suggesting using `$result .= print_r($image_id, true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `var_dump` function doesn't return anything but it outputs its result directly to the browser, so the statement `$result .= var_dump($image_id);` doesn't do anything.

Also there is another problem: the `wp_get_attachment_image_src` return the boolean value `false` or an array. So if an array is returned, you would have an array to string implicit conversion, that at least will result in a notice.

As a starter I would suggest to refactor your `foreach` loop like this:

```
foreach( $image_ids as $image_id ){
        $result .='<li>';
        $result .= $image_id;
        $attachmentImage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'full' );
        $result .= $attachmentImage ? $attachmentImage['url'] : '';
        $result .='</li>';
    }
```

Comment: Had to modify it to the following: `$result .= $attachmentImage ? $attachmentImage['0'] : '';` but your approach worked for me. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely want to assign the result of `var_dump` to your `$result` variable, you could use output buffering as follows:

```
ob_start();
var_dump($image_id);
$result .= ob_get_clean();
```

The `ob_start` function starts buffering output, while `ob_get_clean` gets the output buffer's content and then deletes it.

Answer (score 0):

I used this in one of my projects for logging purposes. This function returns the var_dump content into a string:

```
function varDumpToString($stuff = null) {
  ob_start();
  var_dump($stuff);
  $ret = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  return $ret;
}
```

So just replace this:

```
$result .= var_dump($image_id);
```

with this

```
$result .= varDumpToString($image_id);
```